# Prevent Windows 10 from automatically logging into a passwordless account

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, auto-login

We have a Windows 10 Home version 1607 desktop with two user accounts: an administrator account with a password and a limited account without a password. If I shut down the system without logging out of the limited account first, it automatically logs into that account when I start it up again. We'd prefer that it not do that.

I couldn't find a relevant setting anywhere in the system, whether in the Windows Settings app, Control Panel, or even `control userpasswords2`. There is no access to `gpedit.msc`. How do I prevent the system from logging in automatically, without setting a password for the limited account?

Comment: [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](//superuser.com/q/1018145)

Comment: [Can I disable auto logon on windows 10 home](//superuser.com/q/952868)